# HttpRequest vs HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web page that intercepts POST requests, pulls the username out of the request, and is supposed to forward the request on depending on the username. Now, I notice that the incoming HttpRequest has a Params property, and HttpWebRequest does not. Why is this? Is there a way I can capture the Params data in my outgoing HttpWebRequest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

They're simply two different .Net classes in two different packages:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
   System.Object
      System.MarshalByRefObject
         System.Net.WebRequest
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx

```
   System.Object
      System.Web.HttpRequest
```

HttpWebRequest is an old .Net 1.1 thing - I would definitely use Web.HttpRequest if you're planning on refactoring any code (or writing any new code!)

IMHO...

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was my understanding that HttpRequest is a server class that basically represents an incoming request. If you want to forward the request, you have to recreate the request using the .Net HttpWebRequest. Is this not correct? If I could just create another HttpRequest, that would be awesome.

Comment: I'm not so sure that HttpWebRequest "is an old thing" (like waiting to be deprecated). Take as exemple the new async programming model, using  "async" keyword and returning Task<> (new with .net 4.5). HttpWebRequest already prodides an async read. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For starters, they're completely different classes, in different namespaces. That being said,

`Params` is a wrapper that exposes both querystring parameters as well as POST data. When you are construcing a request you can't write to params, you have to specify what kind of data you are actually adding. So you should add it to the target url as a querystring or you can add it to the body of the request and make it a POST.